# MySql query using GROUP_CONCAT and DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, group-concat

Here is an example query I am doing.  It produces `1,A,1,A,3,B,2,B,4,C,4,C`.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(ID, ','), Value ORDER BY Value) FROM TableName
```

Here's a [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c058/39).

I want to call *`DISTINCT`* on the column `Value` so that it will output `1,A,2,B,4,C` instead.

Is this possible?  Everything I try gives me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the *distinct* combination `Id, Value`, you will need to `GROUP BY value` and select the `MIN(ID)` inside a subquery, then select `GROUP_CONCAT` in the outer query the same way you did.

Something like this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(ID, ','), Value ORDER BY Value)
FROM
(
  SELECT value, MIN(ID) AS ID
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY value
) AS t;
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c058/46)

This will give you:

```
|      RESULT |
---------------
| 1,A,2,B,4,C |
```